# QGIS flip vector (Shape Tool, plugin)

Tags: vector, qgis-3

We need to flip a some vector geometry, like a pancake. We've tried in QGIS 3.10 the Shape Tool, but it's not working. Do any of you have an idea or know a plug-in that would work?

Comment: Could you add more detail on the desired output. Are you trying to just reverse the vertices order or to mirror your shape. May be adding a before/after picture could help clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

You can mirror (transform) your geometry without modifying the original layer. You can just use the symbology and reflect your layer. 
In *Symbology*, open the Layer Rendering area > select *Draw Effects* and click in the yellow star.

[image]

This will open a new tab. Here select *Transform* as *Effect Type* and activate the option that suits your needs (reflect vertical, reflect horizontal or both).

In image one example with England reflected horizontal (in green)
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, for this very comprehensible answer!

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, vote and accept it. And please consider to improve your question to reopen it..